# Optimize hive query

Tags: hive

this query isn't getting completed and gets automatically killed after some 12 hours. I intend to optimize it. I thought of partitioning the cleansing table basis gender column, however, I am not understanding how to left join it once partitioned?

Already explored ways but without any improvement:

1. created index for hh_id and id column, didn't help
2. Submitting this query with 'Tez' engine but got an error
3. tried using /*+ STREAMTABLE  */ while creating table.
4. I also generated hive execution plan, but I couldn't use it to optimize.

Please let me know if some other info I should add here.

Could anyone help with it or suggest some other optimization ideas? Here are some meta details: cleansing table has around 2147542221 rows and 44 rows. There is no null id in pand table and there is one null hh_id in rcd table.

```
'CREATE TABLE db1.NO_MATCH AS 
SELECT dc.staging_id,
dc.hh_id,
dc.source,
dc.no_purchase_flag,
dc.contact_lenses,
dc.week,
dc.dosage,
dc.strength,
dc.strength_na_flag,
dc.do_freq,
dc.freq_as_needed_flag,
dc.do_dur,
dc.birthdate,
dc.birth_month,
dc.birth_year,
dc.price,
dc.sc_da,
dc.trans_da,
dc.vbn,
dc.dr_fo,
dc.gender,
dc.head_flag,
dc.shomember_flag,
dc.awareness_method,
dc.dr_br_na,
dc.con_lens_brand_name,
dc.ail,
dc.re_flag,
dc.dr_sa_flag,
dc.ver_id,
dc.num_pills,
dc.pres_type,
dc.ini_awatype,
dc.co_indi,
dc.co_de,
dc.ve_re,
dc.num_ref,
dc.primreason,
dc.prim_otherspecified,
dc.drplan,
dc.drplan_oth,
dc.HOWORDERED,
dc.ful
FROM db1.cleansing dc
LEFT JOIN (select DISTINCT id from db1.pand) iph ON dc.hh_id = iph.id
LEFT JOIN db2.dim rcd ON iph.id = rcd.hh_id
AND dc.gender=rcd.gender 
AND dc.birth_month=rcd.birth_month 
AND dc.birth_year = rcd.birth_year
WHERE iph.id IS NULL OR rcd.hh_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Can you explain your table strcucture in more detail? 
Why are you joining db1.pand via a distinct id select - isn't the id a unique identifier?
Why is it necessary to condition the join of rcd on gender, bith_month and birth_year of db1.cleansing - as before: isn't the id unique? 
And I think your meta details should be 44 columns - not rows?